# Merging two dataframes in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have a dataframe A:

```
a 1
a 2
b 1
b 2
```

Another dataframe B:

```
a 3
a 4 
b 3
```

I want my result dataframe to be like

```
a 1 3
a 1 4 
a 2 3
a 2 4 
b 1 3 
b 2 3
```

I wondering how I can get the desired result in python. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I'm always wondering whether posting these elementary question is really faster than googling something like  `pandas merge` which gives as a second hit a reference to the pandas documentation titled [Merge, join, and concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple merge using [`df.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) does this:

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['A'])

   A  B_x  B_y
0  a    1    3
1  a    1    4
2  a    2    3
3  a    2    4
4  b    1    3
5  b    2    3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I've tried this before and I got a lot more rows than expected. I checked and found that I've a lot of duplicated rows in the result dataframe. I wonder why would I get duplicated rows when applying this method?

Comment: @YingyingChen This is _exactly_ what you've specified to be your desired output though! Also, this does not give duplicate rows. It does a natural join on the rows.